# sorting network for 8 elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sorting-network

How do I sort a list of 8 elements with sorting network?

for example given the list: 12,5,9,14,33,17,10,8

I know how to sort a list of 4 elements.. what is the rule to sort any list of n elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you would like to sort it, different sorting algorithm may result in different network. You can check [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) about sorting network.